# Safari push notification

Tags: notification

I was wondering.. there is a plugin that provides the Safari push notifications for our ExpressionEngine websities?
there are a couple of plugins for wordpress, drupal and joomla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not personally tested this yet, but another developer just released an extension for my add-ons Postmaster which does this.

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/push-notifications-for-postmaster

So if you want to try that out, you also need Postmaster.

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/postmaster

Answer (score 1):

We developed a solution to use Safari/Web Push Notifications with EE — but since Apples Push-Notification-Service needs server-side scripts and services, this may be hard to accomblish with a EE-AddOn without offer a SaaS behind it to deliver the Notifications.